# Highcharts With Drilldown In IE10+ Does Not Show Underlined Label Style

Tags: javascript, highcharts, internet-explorer-10

Using IE10 (and 11) the drilldown xAxis labels no longer are shown as underlined which is a key visual for users to know they can click it. Is there a workaround for this? I have tried manually setting the style for the drilldown xAxis lables but that seems silly to basically copy the default options into a user option.

This is the default code used for the xAxis lables:

```
activeAxisLabelStyle: {
    cursor: 'pointer',
    color: '#0d233a',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textDecoration: 'underline'         
}
```

To reproduce go to the highcharts drilldown demo [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-drilldown/) in any browser then look go to it in IE10/11.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below css rule.

```
.highcharts-drilldown-axis-label {
   text-decoration:none!important;
}
```

Comment: But why is that necessary? If I manually set the `activeAxisLabelStyle` to what the default settings are it shows. Why is IE10 ignoring the built-in defaults?

Comment: I think it's rather caused by some IE stuff, where simple CSS are broken.. (surprise, surprise). Bug reported [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/3488) - we will see. Thanks!